# How can I pass a PL/SQL cursor record created from multiple tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

This is PL/SQL in a 12c database.

I need to be able to pass a cursor record to a function.  The problem is that the cursor is from three different tables and one of them must use a * to select all of the (hundreds) of fields in that table.
It works if I select distinct fields (from a smaller test table) and it works if I use a select * from one table and no other fields (no other tables involved), but I can't find any way to make this work when selecting from three tables (examples only show two) and using a * (to select all fields) from one of the tables.

I've tried FETCH INTO and SELECT INTO with a pre-defined cursor.  I've tried using a cursor record with a FOR myRecord IN (SELECT a.*, ...) and
creating a matching object (since records can't be created at the schema level)

These work

```
myVarA a%ROWTYPE;
SELECT a.* INTO myVarA  
  FROM a;

SELECT a.myAfield, b.myBfield INTO myVarA, myVarB
  FROM a, b;
```

But I need this to work:

```
myVarA a%ROWTYPE;
SELECT a.*, b.myBfield  INTO myVarA, myVarB  
  FROM a, b;
```

Using a cursor record

```
myRecord        myObjectTypeWithAllFields;      -- ojbect, not record as record can't be declared at schema level

FOR myRecord IN (SELECT a.*, b.myBfield FROM a, b); 
newVar  := myFunction(myRecord);        -- this won't work
```

fails on the function call with PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to myFunction;

The function will do a lot of grunt work that is similar in many packages, but there is also a large amount of unique work
in each package, so I can't just process the entire cursor loop in the function. I really need to pass one row at a time to the function.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a cursor in a package - whether or not you will actually use it - with the same select list:

```
create package p as
cursor c is select a.*, b.myBField
from a, b; -- but use proper join syntax
end;
/
```

Then define your function argument using that cursor's `%rowtype`:

```
create function myFunction(p_record p.c%rowtype) return ... as ...
```

Then your block will work:

```
FOR myRecord IN (SELECT a.*, b.myBfield FROM a, b) LOOP
  newVar  := myFunction(myRecord);
END LOOP;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f0092bc1377f7163b0c70aa621a43a4)

The cursor for loop could then use the cursor defined in the package if you wanted it to.

---

Incidentally, in your object version, the variable declaration:

```
myRecord        myObjectTypeWithAllFields;
```

is redundant; the `myRecord` in `FOR myRecord...` is completely independent. So it doesn't even attempt to use the object type.

Comment: Yes, I thought the explicit "myRecord" declaration was being overridden by the FOR IN statement, so thanks for confirming that.  Creating the cursor in each package is interesting, although there are dozens of packages it would be needed in, so the maintenance would be a trade-off, but perhaps worth it.  I'll take a took at this.

Comment: You only need to create it once, and have everything refer to that one definition.

Comment: First - THANK YOU!  This works and does exactly what I want.  I have many packages that use a similar SELECT - they return the same data, but the WHERE clauses vary and although I can't use the public cursor you showed me how to do/use for all my packages, I can use a representative cursor that allows me to define it and use it as a ROWTYPE in my function definition - and now I can call my function from all the packages.  Again, thank you.  My head hurts from how long I've been banging it on the wall trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a %rowtype anchor so I am assuming an exact fetch. Oracle does not allow to use of multiple records with "into" clauses. But we can have a workaround on that.

```
DECLARE

  emprec EMPLOYEES%ROWTYPE;
  deptname DEPARTMENTS.department_name%type;
BEGIN

  select a.* into emprec
    from EMPLOYEES a
    WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 100;

  SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME into deptname
    from DEPARTMENTS where DEPARTMENT_ID = emprec.DEPARTMENT_ID;
END;
```

This example shows how you can fetch your  a.* in a record and have inner join with another table and have b.myBfield into another record.
And once again these are records so I am assuming it is an exact fetch.
If it is not what you want let me know in the comment.

Comment: I simplified my SELECT for this post and I think I perhaps overdid it.  The actual selects vary with each package and are fairly convoluted, so I'm not sure if I can make this work (I'll give it a shot and modify my post as appropriate).